# Did Jar Jar Binks appear in any of the new Star Wars movies?

Tags: character, star-wars

The *Star Wars* movies *The Phantom Menace*, *Attack of the Clones* and *Revenge of the Sith* feature a character called Jar Jar Binks. As per Wikipedia,

> Jar Jar Binks is a fictional character from the Star Wars saga created
>   by George Lucas. A major character in Star Wars: Episode I – The
>   Phantom Menace, he also has a smaller role in Episode II: Attack of
>   the Clones, and a one-line cameo in Episode III: Revenge of the Sith,
>   as well as a role in the television series Star Wars: The Clone Wars.
>   The first lead computer generated character of the franchise, he has
>   been portrayed by Ahmed Best in most of his appearances.

[image]

After his appearance in Star Wars prequels, what happened to Jar Jar Binks? Did he appear in any other new Star Wars movies, or did the movie makers just remove his character?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what happened to "Jar Jar Binks"?

This part has been total speculation until it was officially stated in the third book (Aftermath: Empire’s End) of  *[Star Wars: Aftermath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Aftermath)*. According to this book, he returned back to Naboo after the Empire rising and dressed up as a clown and started performing in the street. He felt sorry that he let the Empire rising.

From [this Express article](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/768540/Star-Wars-news-Jar-Jar-Binks-fate-Aftermath-Empire-s-End-The-Phantom-Menace)

> According to Mashable, the new book sees **Jar Jar returning to Naboo, where he dresses as a clown and becomes a street performer.**
>
> In one scene a refugee boy called Mapo recognises the accident-prone alien and Jar Jar explains he’s very sad he helped the rise of the Empire.
>
> Jar Jar says: **“Jar Jar makin some uh-oh mistakens. Desa hisen Naboo tink I help the uh-oh Empire.**

Now coming to your second question,

> did he Appear in any other New Star war Movies or Movie Makers Just Remove His character?

No. He didn't appear in two movies of Star Wars sequel trilogy nor in Star Wars original trilogy. This character was created for prequels, but due to criticism of this character, its role  was shortened for the rest of the prequels. However, there is a voice heard in revised version the sixth episode where a voice of possibly a Gungan at Naboo saying,

> Wesa free!

Though, I am not sure if it was Jar Jar or not.